# Worst-case scenario for a SQL operation

Tags: sql, performance, time-complexity

I apologize for the elementary question -

Is it fair to say that the worst-case scenario for executing a SQL operation would be the case in which there are no indices of any kind for the table in question?

I am asked to find how long an operation will take (in hours and # of disk accesses) given the worst case scenario occurs, so I want to make sure I understand what is meant by the 'worst-case scenario' for retrieving data in a SQL table.

The query is 'select name from EMP ssn=9999'

Comment: No... if you are working against current indexes that would be worse than there being no indexes at all. My guess would be that any plan which requires a full table scan per each row would be the worst case scenario.

Comment: In your case, unless the `ssn` field is indexed, there will be a table scan to find that information, which depending on table size, will greatly increase query time and resource usage.

Comment: Consider table locks due to write operations too. Consider the buffer tablespace available for heavy operations (UNDO tablespace in Oracle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better answer your questions, I would like to point out what can cause your query to run slow:
1. Bad indexes.
2. Low I/O rate.
3. Too many operations on the disks outside of your query, in short too much pressure on the database server.
4. Bad query(In this case it might not be applicable).
5. Too much data to be pulled out(Again might not be applicable for your case)
6. Number of records in the table.
7. Table partitioning strategy.
8. Fragmentation on the table.
9. Row/table locks on the table.

I think I should have covered atleast most of the bad things that can happen. I think you should be able to make an informed decision on what variables you want to include in your analysis.